# How to get rid of of those lines going beyond the pictures?

Tags: html, css

[My own website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzcDi.jpg), I've done on the left side, menu bar and on the right side, three pictures stack below each other, with the white space in between.When I did box-shadow on all of the pictures suddenly the padding line began to show up as well. How to remove that? How to do to keep box-shadow only across the picture measurement?

Comment: Where is the padding line? And if you mean the lines on the left side of the images those are the box-shadows

Comment: post your code so we can see what's wrong

Comment: you can see them, they are visible (box-shadow greenish) they are above the picture from the top of the site and on the left side, across the picture going until the menu bar.

Comment: It looks like thanks to you Yong Quan I've solved my own problem. Thank you! :)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: looks like you're applying box-shadow to the container (for example "div") that contains the image and not to the image itself.